# Non Hashable list error

Tags: python

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why?
thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 16, line 4
builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

my code is as follows: (its a dict in a dict but i omitted the other ones to make it easier to read)

```
a = {'nich': {'following': ['caleb', 'daven', 'greg', 'bess', 'john']}}
b = {'search': {'username': 'nich', 'operations': ['following']}}
username = b['search']['username']
operation = b['search']['operations']
main_list = [username]
for op in operation:
        if op == 'following':
            for user in main_list:
                main_list.append(a[user]['following'])
print(main_list)
```

EDIT : print(main_list)
copy &paste error

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of your first line.

Comment: I'm guessing that's from editing the code before posting. The missing `}` would cause a syntax error when it got to `b = ...`.

Comment: Please edit your code into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this means that it should produce the same error you're getting, but still without including any extra code that doesn't impact the results.

Comment: thats a copy paste mistake

Comment: its cut down to the bare bones and will produce the error

Comment: print(str(main_list))

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert a list into another list here :

ie `a[user]['following']` is returning a list

```
for user in main_list:
                main_list.append(a[user]['following'])
```

Instead you should try merging those list:

```
              for user in main_list[:]:
                  main_list = main_list + a[user]['following']
```

[Iterating a copy of the list may be a good idea `for user in main_list[:]:`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney)

Comment: literally jumped out of my seat

Comment: I would use `main_list += a[user]['following']` out of a (possibly misguided) sense that it should offer better performance.

Comment: i keep getting a messsage that says my votes dont count until i get 15 reputation points

Comment: @Galax Since `main_list` is being iterated in the `for` loop, any list added by `+=` would add to the users being iterated. I have no idea from OP's code whether this is intended but since it would be easy to get an infinite loop, (nich follows caleb who follows nich) I doubt it.

Comment: @AkhilThayyil Depending on what OP wants, iterating a copy of the list may be a good idea `for user in main_list[:]:`

Comment: Good point, I didn't look at the code enough to notice that the iterated list was being modified, that's always a bad idea, and yes iterating over a copy is one way around it, or simply build a second list of additions in the loop, and concatenate them onto `main_list` after the loop is done.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks even i didn't notice it, i have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries need their keys to be hashable, which essentially means that you can take the key and turn it into a number. The key (pun intended) is that keys must be *immutable*, meaning that they cannot be changed. If they could be changed, the hash would change. Lists are not hashable because you can change them. This is what `main_list` is:

```
['nich', ['caleb', 'daven', 'greg', 'bess', 'john']]
```

So when you loop through this list...

```
for user in main_list:
    main_list.append(a[user]['following'])
```

The second time through, `user` is a list (because you appended `['caleb', 'daven', 'greg', 'bess', 'john']` to `main_list`). Which is not hashable, so `a[user]` fails. My *guess* is that you want to *extend* the list instead, so that loop should be this:

```
for user in main_list:
    main_list.extend(a[user]['following'])
```

Either that, or use a different (initially empty) list in place of `main_list`.